# Random run through of Prisoner's Dilemma, but doesn't run

Tags: python

```
import random

def move():   
    myScore = 0
    theirScore = 0
    Options=['b','c']
    myChoice=random.choice(Options)
    theirChoice=random.choice(Options)
    if myChoice == 'b' and theirChoice == 'b':
        myScore = myScore-250
        theirScore = theirScore-250
    if myChoice == 'b' and theirChoice == 'c':
        myScore = myScore + 100
        theirScore = theirScore - 500
    if myChoice == 'c' and theirChoice == 'b':
        myScore = myScore - 500
        theirScore = theirScore + 100
    if myChoice == 'c' and theirChoice == 'c':
        myScore = myScore + 0
        theirScore = theirScore + 0
    return myChoice
    return myScore
    return theirChoice
    return theirScore
```

The above is the code I wrote in Python. It is supposed to randomly pick collude or betray, denoted by the strings 'c' and 'b' and change the score accordingly, then return the choices made and new scores. It is a one time use program with no inputs. The following is what happens in my program:

```
In: move
Out: '<function __main__.move>'
```

I have no idea why I am getting this output and any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: 1) You never called `move()` 2) You can't have multiple return statements, but you can return multiple values on one line

Comment: You didn't call the function.

Comment: I forgot the (), may bad and I'll fix the returns, thank you

Answer (score 1):

First, in order to have any output here, you will first need to provide a variable into which the output can be unpacked.

```
myChoice = move()
```

Additionally, only your first return statement will be run, so you will only receive the value of "myChoice" outside of the function. You can remedy this by returning all four values on the same line:

```
return (myChoice, myScore, theirChoice, theirScore)
```

You will then need to unpack all four with the function call as well:

```
(myChoice, myScore, theirChoice, theirScore) = move()
```